# Mysql LEFT JOIN return null values

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.population, CAST(SUM(t2.town_1) AS CHAR) AS town, CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN t2.id LIKE 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR) AS population FROM area1 t1 LEFT JOIN area2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.id like 23
```

Normally it will match if id = 23 exist in both tables. But it's not the case (not in t1 table) so the request return NULL values.
How i can do to return no result?

Comment: A Left join returns all records for the first table even if there is no matching record in the second table.

Comment: @Joe W problem => there is no matching record in the first table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want the result to be matched if the ID exists in BOTH tables, you're looking for an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN.

---

**EDIT:**

On second thought, it's because of your aggregate functions (`SUM`). You're casting them as CHARs (didn't even know you could do that). You should be using a `GROUP BY`. Try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03702/5)

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.population,
  SUM(t2.town_1) AS town,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t2.id LIKE 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS population
FROM
  area1 t1
  INNER JOIN area2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
  t1.id like 23
GROUP BY
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.population
```

On a side note, there's no need for the `like` in your WHERE clause. The way you have it, it's doing the same thing as an `=` sign.

Comment: it returns NULL values with INNER JOIN too

Comment: it's not working with my data but your Fiddle say you're right.